# Python: Append correct string to END of list

Tags: python

I am using the below code that split a bit of text at the first space

```
splitdata = details[2].split(' ', 1)
details[2] = splitdata[0]
details.extend(splitdata[1:])
```

so will take a string like:

> ['(Class 6)', '(0-60, 4yo+)', '1m4f Standard']

and it amends it to:

> ['(Class 6)', '(0-65, 4yo+)', '1m4f', 'Standard']

but i would like the distance to be last. I have played around with the code and looked up multiple tutorials and im sure its easy to do but i have i don't seem to know how to get it to look like the below:

> ['(Class 6)', '(0-65, 4yo+)', 'Standard', '1m4f']

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of your last two lines:

```
details[2:] = reversed(splitdata)
```

Comment: Thanks , i like this answer the most as its 1 extra line of code and will be able to use it in the future else where. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use some python swapping like this,

```
    details = ['(Class 6)', '(0-60, 4yo+)', '1m4f Standard']
    splitdata = details[2].split(' ', 1)
    details[2] = splitdata[0]
    details.extend(splitdata[1:])
    details[2], details[3] = details[3], details[2] # Swap
    print details
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need opposite order of two last elements? If yes, just change order of indices:

```
splitdata = details[2].split(' ', 1)
details[2] = splitdata[1]
details.extend(splitdata[0])
```